# How to get all the configuration options with the uci command in OpenWRT

Tags: shell-script, shell, openwrt

I am configuring a router running OpenWRT, but I am struggling to understand how to use the `uci` command (Unified Configuration Interface) to inspect an existing configuration file. I would like to automate this configuration in a shell script.

Take for example the firewall configuration at `/etc/config/firewall` which is 195 long, so a bit difficult to inspect with `cat`.

There are various rules, take the first one with:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# grep -B1 -A6 'Allow-DHCP-Renew' /etc/config/firewall
config rule
    option name     Allow-DHCP-Renew
    option src      wan
    option proto        udp
    option dest_port    68
    option target       ACCEPT
    option family       ipv4

root@OpenWrt:/etc/config#
```

I can inspect the various fields of this first rule (`@rule[0]`) e.g. the field `name` with:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# uci get firewall.@rule[0].name
Allow-DHCP-Renew
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config#
```

But I can not see the whole rule as output, I've tried with `uci get firewall.@rule[0].*` but it's not the right syntax.

There is no manual for `uci` (`man uci`), so I am not sure where to find the information on how to use that command.

Is this "group get" possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm... Just found out I need to use `uci show` instead of `uci get`, see below for an example:

```bsh
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# uci show firewall.@rule[0]
firewall.cfg0592bd=rule
firewall.cfg0592bd.name='Allow-DHCP-Renew'
firewall.cfg0592bd.src='wan'
firewall.cfg0592bd.proto='udp'
firewall.cfg0592bd.dest_port='68'
firewall.cfg0592bd.target='ACCEPT'
firewall.cfg0592bd.family='ipv4'
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config#
```

Comment: How can you list ALL the rules without knowing ahead of time how many are in the array? `uci show firewall.@rule[*]` doesn't work.

Comment: You could use a bash script to increase an array index until you get an error and collect the results for each iteration

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but wow that is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a script to setup OpenWRT using all current settings on the device.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create OpenWRT setup script
script="/tmp/uci_setup_script.sh"
echo "#!/bin/sh" > "$script"
echo "uci -q batch << EOI" >> "$script"
for section in $(uci show | awk -F. '{print $1}' | sort -u); do
uci show "$section" | awk -F. '{print "set "$0}' >> "$script"
echo "commit $section" >> "$script"
done
echo "EOI" >> "$script"
chmod 755 "$script"
```

If you are using image builder for custom firmware, then create a file for the `files/etc/uci-defaults` folder in the image builder directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create OpenWRT uci-defaults file for image builder
# copy generated file to 'files/etc/uci-defaults/' folder in your image builder directory
script="/tmp/99-custom"
echo "#!/bin/sh" > "$script"
echo "uci -q batch << EOI" >> "$script"
for section in $(uci show | awk -F. '{print $1}' | sort -u); do
uci show "$section" | awk -F. '{print "set "$0}' >> "$script"
echo "commit $section" >> "$script"
echo "EOI" >> "$script"
chmod 755 "$script"
done
```